# Which is the best choice to indexing a Boolean value in lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

Indexing a Boolean value(true/false) in lucene(not need to store)
I want to get more disk space usage and higher search performance

```
doc.add(new Field("boolean","true",Field.Store.NO,Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
//or
doc.add(new Field("boolean","1",Field.Store.NO,Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
//or
doc.add(new NumericField("boolean",Integer.MAX_VALUE,Field.Store.NO,true).setIntValue(1));
```

Which should I choose? Or any other better way?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An interesting question!

- I don't think the third option (NumericField) is a good choice for a boolean field.  I can't think of any use case for this.
- The Lucene search index (leaving to one side stored data, which you aren't using anyway) is stored as an inverted index
- Leaving your first and second options as (theoretically) identical

If I was faced with this, I think I would choose option one ("true" and "false" terms), if it influences the final decision.

Your choice of `NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS` looks good, I think.

Comment: hi,@adrian-conlon,can u help for this? thanks a lot  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464377/using-booleanquery-or-write-more-indexes

Answer (score 3):

Lucene jumps through an elaborate set of hoops to make NumericField searchable by NumericRangeQuery, so definitely avoid it an all cases where your values don't represent  quantities. For example, even if you index an integer, but only as a unique ID, you would still want to use a plain String field. Using "true"/"false" is the most natural way to index a boolean, while using "1"/"0" gives just a slight advantage by avoiding the possibility of case mismatch or typo. I'd say this advantage is not worth much and go for true/false.

Comment: Besides NumericRangeQuery, keep in mind another benefit of NumericField: NumericField is ideal for sorting, because building the field cache is much faster than with text-only numbers.
Source: http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) (a flavour of lucene) - it indexes all basic java types natively.

I've used it and it rocks.

Comment: Interally Solr will still be indexing using lucene though, right?

Comment: @AdrianBaker I expect so, but I've never checked. Implementation choices should typically not be that important to the user of a library/product, because you can't change them and if you're using a library/product you trust it and its choices.