# Best way to index a Boolean in Lucene 4.9

Tags: lucene

This question has been asked and answered previously (link below), but the answer is obsolete.

I want to use Lucene to index a document with a boolean field.  The way recommended in the prior post is:

doc.add(new Field("boolean","true",Field.Store.NO,Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));

However, the class Field is now deprecated. What's the best way to do this today?

[Which is the best choice to indexing a Boolean value in lucene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661489/which-is-the-best-choice-to-indexing-a-boolean-value-in-lucene)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
doc.add(new Field("boolean","true",Field.Store.NO,Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
```

simply adds a non-analyzed string field having value "true".

`StringField` should do the same trick these days:

```
doc.add(new StringField("boolean", "true", Store.NO));
```